# Flutter - using onTap with a list call

Tags: flutter

little messy code I know.

Trying to get the onTap to switch to another page using the categoriesList but get error of "The return type 'String' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context." not exactly sure what the next code should be here.

```
List<Category> categoriesList = [
  Category(name: "nameA", image: "imageA.png", page: "page1"),
  Category(name: "nameB", image: "imageB.png", page: "page2"),
  Category(name: "nameC", image: "imageC.png", page: "page3"),
  Category(name: "nameD", image: "imageD.png", page: "page4"),
  Category(name: "nameE", image: "imageE.png", page: "page5"),
  Category(name: "nameF", image: "imageF.png", page: "page6"),
];

child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => categoriesList[index].page));
                              },
                              child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/${categoriesList[index].image}",
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

Main.dart File

```
import 'package:app/screens/page1.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/page2.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => page1(),
        '/second' : (context) => page2(),
      },
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(color:Colors.blue, centerTitle: true)
      ),
      home: Home(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are passing a String, when you should be passing a Widget:

```
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => categoriesList[index].page1));
```

builder: (context) => categoriesList[index].page1));

The Builder here requires a Widget e.g. `MyPage1(categoriesList[index])` instead of a String.
If you want to navigate, using a String as a RouteName, you should be using something along the lines of

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(
     context,
     categoriesList[index].page);
```

The Names in your List then have to match the Routes in your `main.dart` e.g.:

Your List

```
  Category(name: "nameA", image: "imageA.png", page: "/page1"),
  Category(name: "nameB", image: "imageB.png", page: "/page2"),
  Category(name: "nameC", image: "imageC.png", page: "/page3"),
  ...
```

And your Routes inside main.dart

```
      routes: {
...
    '/page1': (context) => page1(),
    '/page2' : (context) => page2(),
    '/page3':(context) => page3(),...
  },
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't change some copied code.  The question has been edited with the correct code no.  Not every image goes to page1.  Sorry about that.

Comment: So just to make sure I got this right: 
Name and Image are just for the display on this page, all you need for navigating is the name of the page. 
page1, page2, page3 are the Names of the Routes, as specified in your Navigator?

Comment: Correct.  when you press on imageA it will take you to page1, etc.

Comment: In that case, you can use "Navigator.pushNamed(.."  from the the 2nd Codesnippet I just updated.

Comment: ok, works until  I press on image1, then I get the follow error "Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("page1", null) in the _WidgetsAppState."

Comment: Could you update your question with  your RouteSettings in your main.dart?
Since you are navigating with Strings, I'm assuming you use named routes
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

Comment: ok, main.dart has been added to main question.

Comment: just add the `page1`, `page2` & so on pages in the `routes` in main.dart file, Unless you register the names with a corresponding widget, you won't be able to use them to navigate. Also, page1 is registered with `/` as the name, not `page1` as the name

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much